# textfield opens keyboard flutter

Tags: flutter, text, text-editor

As you can see from [the video I posted](https://file.io/kFqFmearxQLU), I have a constraint problem regarding the textfield below. once I press, the keyboard opens but it overlaps and ruins the whole view. how can I solve and manage the problem?

The problem perhaps is that the dimensions for the qrima are badly set.

they advised me to manage everything in a Scaffold and then set resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false but I don't notice any improvements

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    _buttonHeight = size.height * .05;

    double splitPoint = size.height / 7;

    return Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        body: Stack(
            children: [FutureBuilder<UserData>(
          future: contentManager.getUserData(),
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<UserData> snapUserData) {
            if (snapUserData.hasError)
              return Container(
                child: Center(
                  child: Text("There was some error"),
                ),
              );
            if (snapUserData.connectionState != ConnectionState.done)
              return Container(
                child: Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(valueColor: new AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(appColors.yellow)),
                ),
              );
            return Stack(
              alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
              children: [
                // SFONDO
                Positioned(
                  bottom: 0,
                  child: Container(
                    height: size.height,
                    width: size.width,
                    color: appColors.primaryColor,
                  ),
                ),
                // TITOLO
                Positioned(
                  top: size.height * .05,
                  child: Text(
                    localization.showQR,
                    style: Theme.of(context).primaryTextTheme.headline5.copyWith(
                      color: appColors.green,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  top: size.height * .10,
                  width: size.width * .8,
                  child: qrCodeHolder,
                ),
                Positioned(
                  bottom: size.height * .18,
                  width: size.width * .8,
                  child: AutoSizeText(
                    localization.home_subLabel,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    maxLines: 1,
                    style: Theme.of(context).primaryTextTheme.headline5.copyWith(
                      color: appColors.green,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  bottom: size.height * .08,
                  width: size.width * .7,
                  height: size.height * .05,
                  child: TextField(
                    inputFormatters: [
                      new LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(11),
                    ],
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      filled: true,
                      fillColor: Colors.white,
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                      enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18.0,
                      //height: 2.0,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            );
          }),
    ]),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Video is deleted, please share it again.

Comment: You want the view to resize after keyboard appears or not?

Comment: @AVEbrahimi ah sorry https://file.io/kFqFmearxQLU

Comment: You can ser resizeToAvoidBottomInset to true and wrap you whole widget with SingleChildScrollView

Answer (score -1):

Wrap whole content with SingleChildScrollView() widget like below:

```
Scaffold(
  body: SingleChildScrollView( 
    child: Stack( 

    )
  )
)
```

Comment: receive this 
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderStack#afc1e relayoutBoundary=up9 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1940 pos 12: 'hasSize'
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Stack file:///Users/apple/Desktop/Work%202021/toduba-merchant/lib/tabs/home_tab.dart:78:18